# Does $\inf \{|I| : \text{open interval I contains set E} \}=\lambda ^* (E)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For any bounded $E ⊆R$, let $$L(E) = \inf \{|I| : \text{open interval I contains set E} \}$$  if $E$ is unbounded then let $L(E) = +∞$. Does the outer Lebesgue measure satisfy the property $λ^∗(E) = L(E)$ for all bounded $E ⊆R$?

Here is what I think:

We have $$\lambda^*(E)=\inf \{\sum \limits_{j=0}^{\infty}|I_j| : \text{$I_j$ are open intervals}, \, \, E \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{j=0}^{\infty} I_j  \}$$

Since $E$ is a bounded set, we can replace the infinities with say $n$. So we have $$\lambda^*(E)=\inf \{\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n}|I_j| : \text{$I_j$ are open intervals}, \, \, E \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{j=0}^{n} I_j  \}$$ Let $$P=I_1 \cup \dots \cup I_n=\bigcup \limits_{j=0}^{n} I_j$$. Since $I_1, \dots ,I_n$ are open intervals, then $P$ is an open interval. Clearly, $\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n}|I_j|=|P|$. Then  $$\lambda^*(E)=\inf \{|P| : \text{$P$ is an open interval}, \, \, E \subseteq P \}$$ which is equal to $L(E)$. So it does satisfy.

Comment: Well, if you take $E= \{ 1,4 \}$ then $L(E) = 3 \neq 0 =\lambda^*(E)$. Your mistake is believing that a finite union of intervals is an interval. Do you think that $(0,2) \cup (3,5)$ is an interval?

Comment: I see how $\lambda^*(E)=0$ but could you explain how $L(E)=1$ please.

Comment: $L(E) = 3$ because every open interval $I$ that contains $1$ and $4$ contains $(1,4)$ (why?) and $(1,4)$ has length 3, so $L(E) \ge 3$. For the other inequality, consider $(1-\varepsilon,4+\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks, can I just ask, what exactly is a bounded set? Does that mean like finite or countable?

Comment: So a bounded set is like a punctured ball right? and open sets are open balls?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set